# python: NameError：global name '...‘ is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, global-namespace

in my code, I have:

```
class A:
    def a():
        ......

    def b():
        a()
        ......
    b()
```

Then the compiler will say "NameError: global name a() is not defined." If I pull all the stuffs out of the class A, it would be no problem, but how can I define the method in class A? Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it is not the compiler that throws that exception. It is the Python interpreter loop that does that.

Comment: Why would you call a() from inside the class definition?

Comment: @TravisGD I always do this in Java, such as a method is called in another method...

Comment: No, I meant the bottom line. You call a() inside the class definition. Outside a method, inside the definition.

Comment: If you are used to Java **forget it while you are learning/programming in python**. Java is a completely different language; using its paradigms and conventions in python will only produce bad python code. In this case: in python methods are instance attributes exactly like anything else. If you want to access it you *must* first access the attribute from the instance via `self.method_name`. Without the explicit `self` how could you distinguish between a global function and a method(note: functions can be created at runtime -> it's impossible).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to call `self.a()` to invoke `a` from `b`. `a` is *not* a global function, it is a method on the class.

You may want to read through the [Python tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) some more to get the finer details down.